# How to write Apache Jena Inference rule for given rdf data?

Tags: rdf, jena, turtle-rdf, jena-rules

I am trying to build a Apache Jena reasoner node over the below rdf data instance.
I want to write a rule such that the inference api can tell if certain sensor values were out of range. e.g. print statement whose sensor measurement (value of `hasValue`) was not in range 100 to 400.

How do I write a rule using Apache Jena inference api. I tried reading the docs here: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/index.html  but I am getting more confused with the amount of details given.

Should I use RDFS reasoner or OWL reasoner? How do I develop the code exactly for my use case?

```
@prefix iot-context: <http://www.example.org/iot-context#> .
@prefix iot_lite_ins: <http://purl.oclc.org/NET/UNIS/iot-lite/iot-liteInstance#> .
@prefix measurement-iri: <http://www.example.org/iot-instance#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

iot_lite_ins:temperatureSensorA iot-context:hasMeasurement measurement-iri:measurement_123 .

measurement-iri:measurement_123 a iot-context:measurement ;
    iot-context:hasTimeStamp "2022-01-28T11:50:00.352485"^^xsd:dateTime ;
    iot-context:hasValue 456 .
```

I have another rdf schema defining what sensor is located in what region (having `lat` and `long` values in graph). How can I write a rule which answers: Was sensor value out of range in region `abc` (having `lat` = 11 and `long` = 22).

Comment: if you want to write a custom rule, you have to use the generic rule reasoner and use their required syntax: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/inference/index.html#rules - the built-in primitives `lessThan` and `greaterThan` are the way to go I'd say (or `le` / `ge` if range boundaries matter)

Comment: beyond rules you should also think about SHACL if your goal is more the validation of RDF data